# Equals() is insensitive to letter cases in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2022

I have recently been learning LINQ queries to the database. I have encountered quite a weird problem. In my query I am trying to compare 2 strings with the Equal() function. I use the ToUpper() function to have one string in upper case and compare it to the same one but in lower case. The Equals() function is sensitive to the cases of letters, which I checked outside of the query, but the Equals() in the query returns the "true" value. It is really a stupid error, but I really checked if it should work like that and if I didn't make a mistake. I write in C#, work in Visual Studio 2022 and connect to the SQLServer database through the Entity Framework. I am going to put my code below:

```
var wynik = from pracownik in Context.Pracownik
                        let P = pracownik
                        let stan = P.stanowisko.ToUpper()
                        where stan.Equals("informatyk")
                        select new
                        {
                            id_pracownika = P.id_pracownika,
                            nr_departamentu = P.nr_departamentu
                        };

            foreach (var prac in wynik)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prac.id_pracownika + " " + prac.nr_departamentu);
            }
```

Basically the Equals() function returns true to "informatyk"=="INFORMATYK", but only in the LINQ query. Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: [`EF.Functions.Collate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity). Be aware that overriding default collations like this can result in sub-optimal performance since indexes can't be used if the collation doesn't match the column's collation (setting that is another option).

Comment: Do you mean the warriable I created in the "let" clause?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity The best thing to do here is to change the actual collation of the column to case-insensitive, then you don't need any functions at all

Comment: That is a good material, thank you, I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to Entities doesn't perform the actual comparison. Instead, it translate your statements to SQL (or whichever language your database uses) and lets the database worry it.

Depending on which database that you're using, that SQL will look similar to this:

```sql
SELECT id_pracowinka, nr_departamentu
FROM Pracownik
WHERE UPPER(stanow) = "informatyk"
```

By default, SQL Server use case-insensitive collation. (Many other databases such as Oracle and PostgreSQL are case-sensitive by default.)
This can be modified on the tables itself and is probably going to be your easiest way to handle this.

If instead, you'd like LINQ to Entities to render the SQL differently, you'll want to brush up on Expression Trees.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees

Answer (score 0):

SQL server is by default case insensitive. LINQ converts your C# expression tree to a SQL query with `Equals` mapped to ordinary equality checks in SQL Server. As those checks are case insensitive, you get the behavior you see here.

Comment: I understand, is there some way around it?

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your help. Now that I know that SQLServer is case insensitive I understand why my code didn't work as intended and that is what I wanted to know. If everything will be seen as case insensitive then my queries will work as intended if I just am aware of that.

Comment: @Kiks455 - yes. While case-sensitive is the default, you can override that default by changing the collation on the columns that you want to be treated as such. NB - changing this may have implications for the online availability of your data. If you are interested in changing it, I'd suggest a) working with a DBA and b) doing it in a non-production environment first.